# Postgres JSON property value from JSON field returns null

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am facing a problem that took me a lot of time and still did not find any solution or a reason for it.
so I have a table called `test_table` with a column called `data` of type JSON and it holds a value like so:

```
{
"data": null,
"status": -1,
"config": {
    "method": "PUT",
    "transformRequest": [
        null
    ],
    "transformResponse": [
        null
    ],
    "jsonpCallbackParam": "callback",
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
        "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*"
    },
    "timeout": 250000,
    "url": "http://testuser.com",
    "data": {}
},
"statusText": ""
}
```

what I am trying to do is to get the value of `status` only, so I did this:

```
SELECT data->>'status' AS status FROM test_table;
```

the problem is it always return nulls, so any help, please?

I am using Postgres 10.4-R1 on AWS RDS

Comment: It work good https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4ADA63qGwgw7Rth8V3a1p7/0

Comment: Maybe you should show a `CREATE TABLE` and an `INSERT` statement so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @D-Shih yes, I know, the problem is when I run it on PG-Admin it returns nulls.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe they got inserted from a web app which i may not have access, but the table data type is JSON and the data like as I posted.

Comment: The problem is that it works just fine when I try it, so something must be different in your case. You need to investigate and tell us more, else nobody can give you an answer.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe thanks a lot, I just found the issue, as you said, it was with data insertion.